# Disabling reallocation of a resource with Apache Helix 0.7.1

Tags: apache, distributed-system, helix

My use case is to disable the auto reallocation by Helix to a new node temporarily.

I tried using the

> ZKHelixAdmin.enableResource()

API. I see a change in the ideal state[

> {  "HELIX_ENABLED" : "false",...}

] in the Exhibitor but the same resource is getting reallocated to a live instance.

What is the functionality of enableResource() API?The API doc doesn't have much info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The balancer checks if the resource is enabled and only if its enabled it will allocate it to another live instance.

In my case, I was using a custom re balancer[was using the `USER_DEFINED` rebalancer algorithm] and had to add this check explicitly in my custom re balancer.

Works like a charm.